# Can a union have a constexpr destructor if it has a member with non-trivial destructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++23

See this little example:

```
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
    ~Foo() {}
};

union U {
    char dummy;
    Foo f;

    constexpr ~U() {}
};

consteval void bar() {
    U u{};
}
```

This code can be successfully compiled with gcc, but clang rejects it ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sMxs8jbnE)):

```
<source>:10:15: error: destructor cannot be declared constexpr because data member 'f' does not have a constexpr destructor
    constexpr ~U() {}
              ^
<source>:8:9: note: data member 'f' declared here
    Foo f;
    ^
<source>:13:16: error: consteval function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
consteval void bar() {
               ^
<source>:14:8: note: non-literal type 'U' cannot be used in a constant expression
    U u{};
       ^
```

Which compiler is correct?

If clang is correct, is there any way to make the definition of `u` well-formed in `bar` (I can do anything to `U`, but I must keep the non-trivial dtor of `Foo`)?

Note: I don't want to activate member `f`, I only want to take the address of `u.f.y`, which - as far as I understand - should be well-formed because `Foo` has a trivial ctor ([class.cdtor/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1)).

Comment: If `dummy` is the active member, I'm pretty sure you cannot do `&u.f.y` without UB.

Comment: @Jarod42: if `Foo` has a trivial ctor, the standard allows to refer to its members before the ctor runs. See the `int* p3 = &xobj.i;` example [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1). Also, I don't think it's UB, as compilers successfully compile `&u.f.y` in a `consteval` function, which should mean it's not UB: https://godbolt.org/z/99hs83vYz (the example compiles. If you uncomment the ctor - so it doesn't have trivial ctor - then clang doesn't compile it. gcc still compiles it, but I suppose it's a bug).

Comment: My concern is "accessing" non-active members (things that compilers tend to allow because of C).

Comment: Can't you use [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)?

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, accessing inactive members is UB, but just having the pointer value is not. Unfortunately I cannot use `offsetof`, because I'm working with multiple inheritance and not with members.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're allowed to change about `U`? For example, I would change `U` to a non-union class that internally holds a union with an aligned buffer in place of a member of type `Foo`. But then you would need to change the code that uses `U` as well, and perhaps you can't do that.

Comment: [P2448R2](https://wg21.link/P2448R2) is the paper that proposed to relax the requirements on `constexpr` destructors (as well as various other `constexpr` restrictions) such that your example is well-formed. [Clang has not implemented it yet](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx23).

Comment: @BrianBi: thanks for the link of the paper! `U` is under my control, I can do whatever I want with it. But I need a way to take the address of `Foo`'s members, so I think aligned buffer doesn't work in this case. But it seems that I don't need a solution, if according to C++23, my example is well-formed. So the answer is in your comment: both compilers are right; clang rejects the code because it doesn't implement P2448 yet.

Answer (score 0):

### Can a union have a constexpr destructor if it has a member with non-trivial destructor?

`gcc` allows that behaviour, but what `gcc` does isn't the point. For make `Clang` happy, you need to declare your type's destructor `constexpr`:

```
struct Foo {
    int x, y;
    constexpr ~Foo() {}
};

union U {
    char dummy;
    Foo f;

    constexpr ~U() {}
};

consteval void bar() {
    U u{};
}
```

A happily compiled example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WsshPdhqh)

Comment: Two compilers behave differently so it makes sense to know which is right. I cannot make modifications to `Foo`, I mentioned it in the question: "I must keep the non-trivial dtor of `Foo`".

Comment: @geza : The destructor shown here *is* non-trivial – 'trivial' and 'constexpr' are two different things.

Comment: @ildjarn: you're right, that quote is not perfect. I should have said that I couldn't do any modifications to `Foo`. But the main point of my question is not that part. The main point is which compiler is correct (and why). But it seems (see the comments below the question) that my example will be supported by C++23, so I don't need to worry about this.